# Airplay from Ubuntu 14.10 to Speakers

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, settings, speakers, airplay

I would like to stream music *from* my Ubuntu 14.10 machine *to* Airplay speakers.  I followed the instructions [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/apples-airtunes-ubuntulinux/).  After doing so, I can see the Airplay speakers to which I'd like to connect in both System Settings>Sound and/or Pulseaudio Volume Control. I can even select them in those settings.

**HOWEVER,** when I select the Airplay speakers in either System Settings or Pulseaudio, two things happen:

1. **The media player pauses**.  This happens in any media player: FireFox playing Pandora.com or Pithos or any other.  Somehow, simply selecting the Airplay speaker pauses the player, and you **cannot** restart it.  This happens *every* time the Airplay speakers are selected (*note*: I've tried this with numerous AirPlay speakers, so they are not the problem).
2. **The volume for the regular speakers is set at 0.** No idea why.

Most guides that I've read say that all you need to do is what is described in the link -- essentially install Pulseaudio Volume Control and Pulseaudio Preferences, then enable Airplay in the latter.

But it doesn't work for me.  I've tried this on two different installs of 14.10, with the same fail.  [This guy](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181444) seemed to have a similar problem, but no one responded to his post.

Please help me get this to work? It's killing me.

Comment: Pulseaudio only supports the old RAOP protocol (aka *AirTunes*). The newer RAOP2 protocol needs [considerable hacks to get it working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/544251/airplay-sink-no-longer-visible-in-pulseaudio). In case your speakers also support DLNA see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/187086/how-do-i-set-up-live-audio-streams-to-a-dlna-compliant-device

Comment: Takkat, that totally worked!  Since I am trying to use Ubuntu to stream music to an old Android phone (which will be connected to speakers), DLNA works great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Takkat provided the answer as a comment, so I am writing this "answer" to close out my question.  Basically, **AirPlay** is not currently functioning with Pulseaudio without hack.  BUT if **DLNA** is available on your speakers, which they are on any old Android phone connected to speakers, [you can do this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187086/how-do-i-set-up-live-audio-streams-to-a-dlna-compliant-device):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:qos/pulseaudio-dlna
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-dlna
pulseaudio-dlna
```

*NOTE: the last command  turns it on*

*NOTE2:  dependencies for pulseaudio-dlna are listed [here](https://github.com/masmu/pulseaudio-dlna)*

Then you can open either PulseAudioVolumeControl, or just Settings>Volume and select your device.

I'm using BubbleUPnP on my Android.  Please note that you need to turn on BubbleUPnP on the Android *before* you start `pulseaudio-dlna`, else it won't be able to see the renderer.

Comment: Been looking for this for hours, great job. Seems to take a long time to pick up audio changes though (~10 seconds), anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Great, this works for me to stream audio to my Pionner sound sound system.  Only remark: the first command sould be: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:qos/pulseaudio-dlna`

Comment: Seems like, unfortunately, this is still true at least for some devices, in the latest Ubuntu 21.10. I have a SONOS Play 5 speaker. After installing paprefs & pulseaudio-module-raop, then restarting pulseaudio, I get exact same symptoms as the topic-starter. I didn't want the DLNA workaround since I am able to play my music from the iphone, just wanted to have the same ability from the laptop... Sigh...