# Ubuntu machine as an AirPlay receiver

Tags: software-recommendation, airplay

I have a machine with Ubuntu installed and simple speakers connected to this machine via cable. I want to be able to cast music on this machine via my iPhone. Is it possible? What software should I use?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/583624/airplay-from-ubuntu-14-10-to-speakers

Comment: @Rinzwind As i understood the question in the  link is about airplay-powered speakers and the problem is about to cast from ubuntu to speakers. I have different problem: i have simple speakers which connected to ubuntu mahine with cable and i want cast from iphone to this ubuntu machine.

Comment: Simply pairing your Ubuntu machine and iPhone over Bluetooth does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this open source software

https://github.com/abrasive/shairport

```
./configure
make
./shairport -a 'My Shairport Name'
```

Comment: Shairport is no longer maintained since July 2014. Do you know other opensource alternatives ?

Comment: [shairport-sync](https://github.com/mikebrady/shairport-sync) is the currently maintained fork of shairport

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative would be `Shairplay`:

https://github.com/juhovh/shairplay